# Need help identifying grass type

Tags: identification, grass

My yard has been overrun with clover and dandelions. Looking for help identifying the type of grass I have and help controlling the weeds

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFE6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that your photo is inadequate for identifying your lawn grass; typically, it's only really possible to get a good lawn grass ID from personal inspection. I've found [this site](https://getlawnstar.com/blog/grass-identification-guide/), which contains close-ups of the various types of lawn grass (both warm-season and cool-season) and good information about each type. It is missing one characteristic for identification - blade tip. This is commonly missed because lawnmowers, of course, cut off the tips of the grass blades. I recommend that you review the site and then examine your lawn carefully to try to match your grasses (because your lawn probably contains a mix of types) to the site.

Comment: Generally broad leaf weed killers do not hurt any grass so the grass type does not affect the choice of weed killer.

Comment: @blacksmith37 = The question is entitled "Need help identifying grass type", which is why I posted what I posted.